# Um problemão com variáveis em JS e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, variáveis

Eu estou construindo um sistema de registro de livros, é algo bem fácil na verdade, só envolve um pouco de PHP e MySQL, mas o meu problema está na hora da exibição. Veja, são muitas informações, então eu desejei fazer um botão que escondesse a div do livro selecionado com esse método:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Mudarestado(el) {
var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
if(display == "none")
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
else
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Até aí tudo bem,  ele estava escondendo a div, mas eu comecei a adicionar mais e mais livros, e cada um tem seu próprio botão de esconder, e aí está o problema: O botão do primeiro esconde ele mesmo, e os botões dos demais também escondem o primeiro, vejam o código:

```
$div = "div_{$linha['id']}";
// aqui eu mostro os valores de minha consulta
echo "Identificador:     {$linha['id']} <br />";
echo '<div id=".$div.">';
echo "Nome:              {$linha['nome']} <br />";
echo "Autor:             {$linha['autor']} <br />";
echo "Editora:           {$linha['editora']} <br />";
echo "Gênero:            {$linha['genero']} <br />";
echo "Volume:            {$linha['volume']} <br />";
echo "Ano:               {$linha['ano']} <br />";
echo "Número de Páginas: {$linha['numero_de_paginas']} <br />";
echo "Outros Dados:      {$linha['outros_dados']} <br />";
echo "</div>";
echo '<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado(\'.$div.\')">Mostrar/Esconder</button><br /><br />';
```

Já tentei mudar a variável $div, acrescê-la, imprimí-la na tela para identificar algum erro, parece realmente impossível! Peço a colaboração da comunidade para me ajudarem a resolver esse problema, e também desculpas se fiz algo errado nesse post, é a minha primeira vez num fórum.

Comment: Tente assim `echo "Identificador: ".$linha['id']." <br />";` e depende seu parâmetro de php esta utilizado de declaração, Se esta tentado de colocar variavel php para javascript, não bem funciona. São diferente linguagem.

Comment: Não deu certo ;-;. Mesmo assim, muito abrigado por propor uma solução.

Comment: Pra que está usando `{ }` ? se esta tentado para AngularJS?

Comment: Bom, eu imaginei que como o resultado da query exibiria vários resultados, era necessário uma div para cada livro.

Comment: Certo, se esta usando MySQL correto, precisa utilizar repetição para resultar de vetor. Utilize `mysql_fetch_array` e segue o exemplo http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Eu estou usando: fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).

Comment: Entendi e perdão nem uso pdo, se esta usando PDO é diferente de php, coloca tags ai `PDO`.

Comment: Tudo bem amigo! Eu agradeço sua ajuda e me desculpe se não fui específico nas tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O id (identificador) no html deve ser unico, por isso só vai funcionar na primeira div encontrada, tente alterar seu código para o seguinte:

```
// aqui eu mostro os valores de minha consulta
    echo "Identificador:     {$linha['id']} <br />";
    echo '<div id="div_{$linha['id']}.">';
    echo "Nome:              {$linha['nome']} <br />";
    echo "Autor:             {$linha['autor']} <br />";
    echo "Editora:           {$linha['editora']} <br />";
    echo "Gênero:            {$linha['genero']} <br />";
    echo "Volume:            {$linha['volume']} <br />";
    echo "Ano:               {$linha['ano']} <br />";
    echo "Número de Páginas: {$linha['numero_de_paginas']} <br />";
    echo "Outros Dados:      {$linha['outros_dados']} <br />";
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado(\'div_{$linha['id']}.\')">Mostrar/Esconder</button><br /><br />';
```

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, mas agora ele não está ocultando nada. Acho  que estou colocando algum valor incorreto na variável  $div, pois não funcionou :(

Comment: Inspecione sua página, no navegador e veja o que esta sendo escrito no id da div e se na função onclick esta chamando a função correta (no seu caso esconder) e está passando o id da div corretamente.

Comment: @Zenas atualizei o codigo, tenta ver se agora funciona, talvez o valor de $div possa ser string o que prejudica na execução do JS

Comment: Débora, a div do código lá em cima está em conflito, pois o original é Mudarestado, mas eu mudei para Esconder para facilitar a compreensão do código, não vi que em baixo também tinha que mudar. Obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: @flfonseca, como você acha que eu devo declarar a variável $div? No momento ela está: $div = "div_{$linha['id']}"; Mesmo depois de mudar tudo, está acontecendo a mesma coisa que eu descrevi lá na pergunta. O código inteiro, lá em cima, foi atualizado.